# jquery .click function doesn't fire when click menu

Tags: jquery, asp.net, function, menu

I am using menu in my aspx pages with using jquery.click. in my asp.net page.

if page not include parameters (such as "mypage.aspx) click function is work fine and my menu opening ,but when I open page with parameters (such as "mypage.aspx?id=3),in page ,my click function doesn't work and menu not open.

This is my jquery.click function:

```
// Show menu
$("a.showMenu").click(function () {
    if (menuStatus != true) {
        $(".ui-page-active").animate({
            marginLeft: "165px",
        }, 300, function () {
            menuStatus = true
        });
        return false;
    } else {
        $(".ui-page-active").animate({
            marginLeft: "0px",
        }, 300, function () {
            menuStatus = false
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

This is my html code (which open menu) in mypage.aspx

```
<a href="#" class="showMenu"><img src="images/icon-menu.png" alt="Menu" border="0" /></a>
```

How can I do?

Comment: where you set the first time `menuStatus`? Probably the error is there

Comment: thanks but i try to change  else section,marginleft:0px to 30 px,but nothing change

Comment: You are using a variable, `menuStatus`, that is not defined in this click handler. Where does `menuStatus` get its value from?

Comment: Not sure why it's not working, but as a sidenote you could have just done [**THIS**](http://jsfiddle.net/7VXKp/1/), also console.log your variables and use console.logs inside the click function to make sure it's firing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good test to try, just to see if the jQuery is working:

```
// Show menu
$("a.showMenu").click(function () {
    alert('I am here'); // <---
    if (menuStatus != true) {
        $(".ui-page-active").animate({
            marginLeft: "165px",
        }, 300, function () {
            menuStatus = true
        });
        return false;
    } else {
        $(".ui-page-active").animate({
            marginLeft: "0px",
        }, 300, function () {
            menuStatus = false
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

If not, then have you referenced the jQuery.js file?  Something like:

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the comments are mentioning; `menuStatus` is the key.  Where is that being set initially?

I created a jsFiddle for you.  I just used text instead of your image but it should help.  Notice that I am initializing `menuStatus` to false.

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/vbGRQ/)

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it worked. I'm not sure where's your problem.

[In this fiddler, I tested your code and it worked](http://jsfiddle.net/jupaol/vYZNR/2/)

[And in this fiddler, I removed the `menuStatus` flag](http://jsfiddle.net/jupaol/5dPXv/)

In order to remove the `menuStatus` flag, I changed the `click` function for: `toggle`

If you could be more specific about your error it would be easier to detect the problem

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone,but i found solution myself.

The problem was ,where i created send link.

my old code is:

```
  <a href="mypage.aspx?id=3" >Go to My Page</a> »
```

i added rel="external" and my menu worked everytime!

```
   <a href="mypage.aspx?id=3" rel="external">Go to My Page</a> »
```

Thanks anyway!